# Mapping an infinite set of numbers to a finite set

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers, programming

Not a mathematician but a programmer here.

Let us say I have an infinite set of numbers (that is a series) $X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3\dots\}$

I want to map each element in X, to a number in a finite set of numbers $Y = \{0, 1, 2\dots n\}$. $n$ is known and it is a natural number sequence.

The first operation I thought of was to have $X \mod n$ (modulus) to generate the mapping. My question- Are there any other operations that yield such a mapping between $X$ and $Y$ which are different from modulus?

If there are certain numbers missing in the natural sequence Y, what would be an approach to achieve the mapping?

Comment: You just want a mapping , right? Or are you expecting some pattern to be satisfied by the mapping?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Random mappings into the finite set are fine. But with the property that a particular number in X has to map to the same number in Y any time the operation is applied.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, +1

Comment: What do you mean by a map? For example, mapping everything in $X$ to $0$ is a perfectly good map for me.

Comment: What about mapping each $x_i$ to $i$ for all $i < n$ and $x_i$ to $n$ for all $i \geq n$?

Comment: Combining the ideas: what about $x_i\mapsto (i\mod (n+1))$?

Comment: @DuduBob I would like to have maximum coverage in Y to as many numbers as possible, instead of to just one element that you suggested.

Comment: @jojobo The cardinality of X is huge compared to the cardinality of Y. So in your suggestion, for i >= n, everything maps to the same number "n". I am looking for something that wraps around or having almost equal probability of an element in Y to be picked.

Comment: @Keshav My point is that basically anything is a valid map. For example, what about mapping $x_{77}$ to $0$, $x_{99}$ to $1$, and $x_{100k}$ to $k$ for $k \geq 2$, and all others to $6$?

Comment: @Berci In your suggestion it would become dependent on the position or index of an element in X and the generated mapping would repeat exactly after "n" numbers. Instead I am looking for a transformation that gives weight to the content of X itself.

Comment: Please update the question with these more and more specific requirements.

Comment: @Keshav: when you ask mathematicians a question like this you really need to be very clear about the actual requirements you want. Obviously there are many silly maps and most of them will probably not do what you want, but you haven't made it at all clear what it is you want, so nobody knows how to answer your question. Do you want a hash-like function, for example? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function